Specifying a Function as a Character String and Subsequently Using It to Perform an Operation
I have the following vector.
Vector_1 <- 1:10

I want to define a constant called Function_to_Use that can take values of either "sum" or "mean". Then, I want to somehow convert this character string (the Function_to_Use object) into an actual function and use it on my vector.
What are some good ways to accomplish this task?
Thanks!

Use Function_to_Use<-"sum" then get(Function_to_Use)(Vector_1) or match.fun(Function_to_Use)(Vector_1)
